# How to create regexp parsing pascal-like function declaration with body?

Tags: regex, pascal

How to create (and is this possible) regexp parsing pascal-like function declaration with body ?
I've created some regexp

```
 function\s+(\w+)(\(((((var\s*)?(\w+)(\s*\,+\s*)?)+?\s*\:\s*(\w+)\s*\;?\s*?)\s*)+\))?\s*\:\s*(\w+)
```

which can pool only functions prototypes (it works only if there is no comments, so i clear comments before parsing ) and i have no idea how to change it to make it pool functions with bodies. The problem is there are can be many of "begin - end" blocks, so it is hard to find functions ending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you are using the wrong tool. Programming languages have a context-free structure that regular expressions simply cannot recognize reliably. Properly nested parentheses like `{ () [] } { }` are an example for such a context-free structure for which you cannot find a regular expression that checks the proper nesting.

To solve the problem, you could use regular expression to break down program code into a stream of tokens and then use a (manually coded) top-down parser to check the structure of this token stream. To learn about this, consult any book about compiler design. Scanning (breaking into tokens) and parsing (checking structure) are always the first chapters. The [Wikipedia entry for a top-down parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) provides an example.

Comment: Regular expressions in a computer theoretical sense don't support such constructs. But I think many RegEx implementations have special features which support such matches. I think its called balanced groups or something like that. Personally I'd still prefer writing a clean parser for such grammars.

Comment: @CodeInChaos You are right that many RE implementations go beyond the theoretical limits but they have to give up the performance guarantees provided by RE theory as a consequence (cf. http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). Perl, for example, provides constructs to recognize context-free structures. A cleaner approach is Lua's LPeg framework that unifies parsing and scanning. Functional languages might use parser combinators to the same effect. Unless you have something like this available, I'd still recommend to use a parser explicitly.